# React Apollo GraphQL, many queries, but one component to be reused

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have this situation:

*TeamComponent.js:*

```
....more code
  <WorkItemComponent workType="Beautiful">
  <WorkItemComponent workType="VeryBad">
....more code
```

*WorkItemComponent.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import { compose, withHandlers } from "recompose";
import MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY from "./MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY";
import MY_VERYBAD_WORKTYPE_QUERY from "./MY_VERYBAD_WORKTYPE_QUERY";
import AmazingComponent from "./AmazingComponent";

class WorkItemComponent extends Component {
  <AmazingComponent/>
}

export default compose(
  graphql(MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY), // <-- here I need to change this query
  choosing from [MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY, MY_VERYBAD_WORKTYPE_QUERY] based on "workType" prop in parent component "TeamComponent".
  withHandlers({
    ...
  })
)(WorkItemComponent);
```

I need to change the query "`MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY`" choosing  *`MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY`* or *`MY_VERYBAD_WORKTYPE_QUERY`*
   based on "`workType`" prop in parent component "`TeamComponent`".

**But how?!**

Maybe I have to rethink everything?

**Where am I wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two easy approaches you could take here:

1) Execute *both* queries ... and choose which results set you want *inside* WorkItemComponent. Obviously this is slightly wasteful as you'll be running one query you don't need.

2) Export two different components. Wrap them in a 3rd component that does the choosing. Example code:

```
const handlers = withHandlers({
  ...
});

const ComponentOne = compose(
  graphql(MY_BEAUTIFUL_WORKTYPE_QUERY),
  handlers
)(WorkItemComponent);

const ComponentOne = compose(
  graphql(MY_VERYBAD_WORKTYPE_QUERY),
  handlers      
)(WorkItemComponent);

const Switcher = ({workType}) => workType === "something" ? <ComponentOne/> : <ComponentTwo/>;

export default Switcher;
```

So, compose up two different components, and switch between them at render time. Functional components and recompose make this rather simple and elegant!